# react native cors axios get

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

good evening I have a mobile program I can not overcome in any way Corse as I did not try the goal of the day to throw requests does not work in any way and gives such an error

const test = await axios.get(`http://site-api.esculab.com/api/site/getArticlesShort`, {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',

})
in ract I was solving this problem add "proxy": "https://site-api.esculab.com/" in package.json and const getPunks = async () => { const result = await axios.get( '/api/customers/getPunkts') }
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXZ9J.png
[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Seems like this api doesn't set cors headers on backend

Comment: What language did you use for backend . Did you configure cors in back-end ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue of CORS policy: No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is occurring due to headers not being set in the backend site. When the API call is made then this issue will trigger. Once the headers are set at the backend then this issue wouldn't occur.